# How to add icon in Nearby notification using google proximity beacon api

Tags: beacon, google-nearby, google-proximity-api

I want to add my icon in Nearby notification message as attachment which I am creating using google proximity beacon api using com.google.nearby/en namespace

Answer (score 2):

Are you referring to the Favicon Icon displayed on the left side with Notification Message and URL?
To do that, Your URL need to pass the following Google Favicon Rules:

1. Favicon Icon size must be greater than 32x32.
2. It shouldnt be SVG format (PNG/ICO/JPG is acceptable).
3. Favicon link tag must be inside `<Head>` tag

   `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=4f32ecc8f43d">`

Let me know if that's work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The icon that shows on a Nearby Notification is based on the favicon of the target website. You don't add it as an attachment in the Google Beacon Dashboard, but rather, just make sure your target website has a favicon installed that complies with favicon rules (see Vaibhav's answer on this for more details).